# Range Initialization of a C Array

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

Very simple question of **where** does this code work?

```
static void *gostruct[] = 
{
    [0 ... 255] = &&l_bad,
    ['\t'] = &&l_loop, [' '] = &&l_loop, ['\r'] = &&l_loop, ['\n'] = &&l_loop,
    ['"'] = &&l_qup,
    [':'] = &&l_loop,[','] = &&l_loop,
    ['['] = &&l_up, [']'] = &&l_down, // tracking [] and {} individually would allow fuller validation but is really messy
    ['{'] = &&l_up, ['}'] = &&l_down,
    ['-'] = &&l_bare, [48 ... 57] = &&l_bare, // 0-9
    ['t'] = &&l_bare, ['f'] = &&l_bare, ['n'] = &&l_bare // true, false, null
};
```

Reading through it its clear to see that it initializes an array containing 256 entries to the value &&l_bad and then overrides certain indexes with specific values. But this code does not compile in VS2010 which is what I have access to so I am wondering where this is valid C code.

NOTE: This code snippet was taken from a [JSON parser on github](https://github.com/quartzjer/js0n/blob/master/js0n.c) that, from my understanding, creates jump tables for the processing of JSON strings.

Comment: I believe this is using a gcc extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This construct is called **[Designated Initializers](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC82)**.
Using *Range* in Designated Initializers is a GNU gcc specific extension.

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write *`[first ... last] = value`*
>   . This is a GNU extension. For example,
>
> ```
> int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
> ```

Compiling it with `-pedantic` shall tell you so.
Note that it is non-portable since it is a compiler specific extension.

Comment: Designated initializers are not a gcc extension (except that gcc permits them in C89 mode), but the use of `...` in designated initializers is.

Comment: Thank you, searching for this syntax is fairly difficult in most search engines it seems so the name of this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is using a number GNU C extension.

http://www.gnu.org/s/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html

```
'as a GNU C extension, you can initialize a range of elements 
to the same value, by specifying the first and last indices, in the 
form [first] ... [last]'

'As a GNU C extension, you can also take the address of a label 
with the label address operator &&. The result is a void* pointer 
which can be used with goto.'
```

It looks like this is most likely being used as a jump table for a parser, 
that entire section will need to be rewritten if you intend to port it to windows.

You'll probably find that you will implement a simple switch statement and replace
the lookup and goto jumps, something like perl will help you with the 'typing'
excersise :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the reference

> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C90 mode as well. This extension is not implemented in GNU C++.

Both range and specific initializer are ISO C99 supported, and are not only GNU extension. You can try to enable ISO C99 (I don't know how) in Visual Studio 2010.

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: This may help others in addition to the information above. Microsoft's support for C standards in their C++ environment is on an as-needed basis most of the time. If a standard/feature is not in heavy demand then it is generally. Since there is a view of goto being avoided at all times (instead of understanding every logic or func call is a goto) it's not likely to have this supported in Visual Studio. (I have not checked recently however)

Answer (score 1):

Using ranges in designated initializers is an gcc extension, not supported in standard C99.

Also the code takes the address of labels, which I believe also is a gcc extension.

So, no this is not valid C code, just valid gcc c code.