# How to initialize several struct variables at once?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

For a struct like

```
struct data{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};
```

how can I initialize several instances of that struct with identical values at once?

Instead of:

```
struct data object1 = {0,0,0}, object2 = {0,0,0}, object3 = {0,0,0};
```

Comment: What does "identical values" mean? Could it mean `{1,2,3}` for all the objects or only `{0,0,0}` always?

Comment: Initializing all fields to `int 0` is one thing.  Initializing to non-zero "identical values" is another.  Which one is your goal?

Comment: See [Range Initialization of a C Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7803861/2410359)

Comment: Any particular reason with this is tagged `arrays`?

Comment: Initializing with any value.
The 0,0,0 was just for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I initialize several instances of that struct with identical values at once?

Not really "*at once*", whatever this is meant to mean, but at least without repeating yourself (that is following [the DRY-principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)) you could do:

```
int main(void)
{
  struct data object1 = {1, 2, 3}, object2 = object1, object3 = object1;

  ...
}
```

or with each definition on a separate line:

```
int main(void)
{
  struct data object1 = {1, 2, 3};
  struct data object2 = object1;
  struct data object3 = object1;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, among all the good suggestions, yours appeals to me the most.

Answer (score 4):

You can take an array of the `struct`s and use a single brace-enclosed initializer, like

```
 struct data object [3] = {0};
```

go have multiple *variables* of that structure type, all initialized to `0` (or equivalent).

This makes use of a special property of initialization, quoting `C11`, chapter

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a
>   particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject;<sup>151)</sup>
>   all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as
>   objects that have static storage duration.

and, initialization for objects having `static` storage,

> [...] If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

That said, in case you don't want all the values to be initialized to `0`, there are alternate ways. As mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41396017/2173917) by Mr. Jonathon Reinhart, you can make use of designated initializers.

Comment: Nice and short but only if all data should be set to 0. For a more generic sense of "identical values" this will not work.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The text part does not mention this limitation. I assume the example is just a poor one. If he wanted to have it all 0 then he would probably tell us directly instead of using a generic "identical values" phrase.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I tend to favor the Linux kernel style and strongly prefer [*designated initializers*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

I would do what they do, and create a macro for initializing your struct. That makes it easy to add elements and control how they are initialized.

```
struct data {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

#define INIT_DATA { \
    .a = 0, \
    .b = 0, \
    .c = 0, \
}
```

And use it like this:

```
struct data mydata = INIT_DATA;
```

Continuing with the Linux style, you wouldn't have more than one of these variables on a line anyway. It makes different easier to look at when variables are added/removed. What is wrong with:

```
struct data old_data = INIT_DATA;
struct data new_data = INIT_DATA;
```

If you have more than a couple, should they be individual variables or should they be an array? If so, you can take advantage of a GNU extension to initialize a range:

```
struct data datas[N] = {
    [0 ... N-1] = INIT_DATA,
};
```

Otherwise, you will need to use a regular old loop to initialize your data at run-time.

Comment: Finally got to the part about initializing a range using a GNU extension.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the GNU extension, yet `[0 ... N]` looks wrong.  Is that  specifying elements `0,1,2...N` (`N+1` elements) for an array of `N`?  (one too many)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Now this is much better, upped. Also, cited the reference to your answer in mine. :)

Comment: @chux Yes you are correct; I've changed it to `N-1`. I've gotten to used to Python's slicing, where the lower bound is inclusive and the upper end is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of structures and initialize them in a loop.

```
struct data array[N_ITEMS];

for(i=0; i<N_ITEMS; i++)
{
    array[i].a=a;
    array[i].b=b;
    array[i].c=c;
}
```

If you want to initialize all fields to 0, you can use memset:

```
 memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: *"If you want to initialize all fields to the same value, you can use memset."* This is **dangerous** advice as memset only works with bytes so it can only be used to initialize the whole thing to zeros.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart you're right. Although in this case, if he wanted to init with some exotic value (such as -1) he could still use memset.

Comment: While you're technically correct, such hackery would never make it through a code review as it's a landmine.

Comment: It was not mentioned that the values should be same for all fields. Also not same bytes within all fields. The value should just be identical for all instances of the struct. memset is definitely not a suitable option.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: And only if the bit-representation of any pointers in the structure is all-0 for `NULL`. And only if the bit-representation of any floating-points in the structure is all-0 for `0.0`. And <et cetera ...>.

Comment: Agreed, it's generally bad. That said, are there any architectures in existence today where those values are not all zero bits?