# C - What does this function pointer declaration mean?

Tags: c, arrays

I am analyzing some multithreading code. In an initialization function, there is a piece of code like this:

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_STREAMS;i++){
    cmdStreamTaskPtr[i] = NULL;
}
```

I understand that syntax, but my problem is in the declaration of `cmdStreamTaskPtr`. It is defined in the following way, where `cmdData_t` is a `typedef struct` and `MAX_STREAMS` is 5.

```
static cmdData_t *(*cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS])(void) = {[0 ... MAX_STREAMS-1] = NULL};
```

I have no idea what this line means. Is it a variable with a default value?

Comment: You might find [this site](https://cdecl.org/) useful...

Comment: Do we have a canonical dupe target for this kind of questions?..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I actually tried it and that site doesn't seem to handle this particular declaration. It complained about a syntax error, even after I removed the initialization part of the statement.

Comment: You could replace the macro with a number and the type with some standard type. These things it doesn't know

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`cmdStreamTaskPtr` is an array:

```
cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS]
```

Of pointers:

```
*cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS]
```

To functions that accept no arguments:

```
(*cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS])(void)
```

And return a `cmdData_t *`:

```
cmdData_t *(*cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS])(void)
```

And is `static`:

```
static cmdData_t *(*cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS])(void)
```

That array is then initialized with `NULL` for all array members:

```
static cmdData_t *(*cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS])(void) = {[0 ... MAX_STREAMS-1] = NULL};
```

Note that the initialization syntax `[0 ... MAX_STREAMS-1]` is *not* standard C but an extension supported by GCC.  It's also redundant in this case because the array is declared as `static`, meaning it has static storage duration and therefore its elements are implicitly initialized to `NULL` if not explicitly initialized.

The use of function pointers can be made more clear with a `typedef`.  In this situation, we can create the following typedef:

```
typedef cmdData_t *(*fp)(void);
```

This makes `fp` a typedef for a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning a `cmdData_t *`.  The array definition can then be changed to:

```
static fp cmdStreamTaskPtr[MAX_STREAMS];
```

So now it should be more clear that `cmdStreamTaskPtr` is an array of `fp`, where an `fp` is the previously defined function pointer.

Comment: Is the `[0 ... MAX_STREAMS-1] = NULL` a compiler extension? I've never seen that syntax before. edit: [it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7803912/5522303)

Comment: Note that the initializer is 100% redundant. The variable is `static`, so it'll be zero-initialized by default.

Comment: Would you mind writing a very simple code similar to the declaration by calling the declaration's definition as a function? I would like to examine it for fully educational purpose, _please_.

Comment: @snr Such a function could be called like `cmdData_t *var = cmdStreamTaskPtr[0]();`

Comment: Now, do it with `typedef` - just as an example of *why* `typedef` is useful here. ;-)

Comment: @jcmiguel Did this answer your question?

Comment: @dbush, yes, it did. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

`cmdStreamTaskPtr` is an array of pointers to functions that take no arguments and return pointers to `cmdData_t`'s.  You can tell by reading the declaration as a usage: `cmdStreamTaskPtr` is subscripted first since subscripting has a higher precedence than dereferencing, then the result is dereferenced, and then the result is called on void (nothing) and if the result of the function call is dereferenced we finally get a `cmdData_t`.  The `static` storage duration specifier applies to the array and is redundant since global variables are static by default.  Moreover, the code `{[0 ... MAX_STREAMS - 1]= NULL}` uses a ranged designated initializer, which is a gnu extension to the C language, to set everything to null, which is redundant for three reasons: unspecified elements of an initializer list are set to zero automatically, static storage variables are set to zero automatically, and there is code later that sets the array to zero.

Comment: `static` is never redundant. If this is really a global variable, `static` gives it internal linkage.

Comment: "... global variables are static by default. " --> no.

Comment: @chux: Well, it is half right. Global objects do have static storage duration. Still, it is wrong to say `static` is redundant here, but because it affects linkage, not storage duration. Which an annoying thing for a storage-class specifier to do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True global objects do have _static storage_ duration.  Yes, wrong to say `static` is redundant - you can say that again - [DORD](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Department_of_Redundancy_Department) ;-)