# In struct nested union/array member default initialization compiles, but is not happening correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, nested, initialization, unions

I am trying to initialize array members at struct declaration in the following struct with nested union & array:

```
struct Nested
{

  union 
  {  
    short sArray[5] = {42};
    float fVal;  // Must NOT be initialized - obviously, only 1 member of a union can be
  };

  double dArray[5] = {77.7};

};
```

While the code compiles just fine, only first elements of both arrays are initialized, when running/debugging the code..

sArray[0] is set to 42, remaining elements are all set to 0
dArray[0] is set to 77.69999, remaining are all set to 0

All other answers I found, mention initialization at instance declaration, but not default init in struct/class declaration.
I have not seen/found whether this syntax is enabled (for array members too) by gnu c++17.
However, since it compiles WO warning one would assume it should correct.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Edit:
Or how do I simply initialize my arrays ?

Comment: `= {42}` always only initializes the first array member to the value and the rest to zero. I don't understand what is special about the situation you have in comparison with just a normal array declaration at block scope.

Comment: `short sArray[5] = {42, 51, 89, 76, 42};` would initialize all values with non-zeros.

Comment: @user17732522 yeah, right.. I was confused about the syntax. I know something similar is possible in C, or Python..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803861/range-initialization-of-a-c-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), which means the elements in `sArray` and `dArray` are [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) when not specified. Because `short` and `double` are scalar types, this means [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

Since you don't specify anything but the first element, all remaining elements will be initialized to 0

As requested in the comments, a way to initialize the arrays would be `std::fill` or `std::fill_n`:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct Nested {
    explicit Nested() {
        std::fill_n(sArray, 5, 0);
        std::fill_n(dArray, 5, 0.0);
    }
    union {
        short sArray[5];
        float fVal;  // Must NOT be initialized - obviously, only 1 member of a
                    // union can be
    };

    double dArray[5];
};
```

In general, I would recommend to instead use `std::array` and its `fill` function:

```
#include <array>

struct Nested {
    explicit Nested() {
        sArray.fill(0);
        dArray.fill(0.0);
    }
    union {
        std::array<short, 5> sArray;
        float fVal;  // Must NOT be initialized - obviously, only 1 member of a
                    // union can be
    };

    std::array<double, 5> dArray;
};
```

Comment: All right, I see. I was apparently confused from other languages like C#/Java...
So I guess in c++17 we do not have available range array initialization like in C ? :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803861/range-initialization-of-a-c-array

Comment: @SoldOut Apart from declaring the array without initializing and then using `std::fill`, I don't know of a built-in way to do this in C++. It is definitely possible to make one via variadic templates, but that is probably harder to read than `short sArray[5]; std::fill_n(sArray, 5, 42);`

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Appreciate so much !  
Btw, I cant add the addressing @eike at the begin.. - keeps erasing it as i post.

Comment: @SoldOut Thats probably because you are commenting on my answer, so I get notified anyways.

Comment: Would U like to adit/add solution to my edited and now expressed need ?
I.e. call std::fill_n(sArray,LENGTH,42);  in constructor ?
And I'll make this the THE answer :)